# Is it better to store one tsvector column for all fields or one tsvector column per field?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Consider a simple `movies` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE movies(
    id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title character varying(255),
    categories character varying(255),
    summary text,
    description text
);
```

Suppose I am interested in doing full-text search on all the fields like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM movies
WHERE to_tsvector(title) @@ to_tsquery('Lumberjack')
OR to_tsvector(categories) @@ to_tsquery('Lumberjack')
OR to_tsvector(summary) @@ to_tsquery('Lumberjack')
OR to_tsvector(description) @@ to_tsquery('Lumberjack')
```

Clearly I should not be using `to_tsvector` at runtime like that and should cache the `tsvector` representation of the fields instead. But I see two ways of doing that:

1. Store one `tsvector`-representation column for all of the fields
2. Store one `tsvector`-representation column per each field

Which is more performant and why?

Comment: What are your requirements? Are your users expecting to type "Lumberjack" and have it match any of the fields? In that case I would index one `tsvector`.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Yes, those are the requirements. Couldn't I achieve that with multiple `tsvector` of each of the fields (title, categories, summary, description) though? If not, then in which case would such a setup be useful?

Comment: Are all queries going to go against all fields, or will the user have a set of checkboxes to pick any combination of them?

Comment: @jjanes All queries. But I'm also interested in an argument for the setup you've mentioned.